# textview as heading to listview

Tags: android

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/_tv_title_labels"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Profile Labels :"
    android:textColor="@drawable/normal_text_color"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />


<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/asda"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/TableLayout01"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/_lv_labels"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hi i have list view with the text view as heading but there is more space below the textview heading .how to avoid the space .[image: remove space below textview]
in this image u can find the space i need to avoid space

But this free space is found above the button when the free space is removed below text.
my page should not contain free space.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `TextView` inside the `RelativeLayout` and use `android:layout_above="@+id/asda"` in your `TextView` to set it above the `LinearLayout` removing any space.

Here is the code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="TextView" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" >
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i have added the textview inside the relative layout as u said but the text name is not shown it is invisible.

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to set the the TextView On top of the ListView Use the
>   below shown XML It is to display TextView on the top of the ListView.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/_tv_title_labels"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="Profile Labels :"
        android:textColor="#de9089"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/_lv_labels"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="380dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/_tv_title_labels"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/_tv_title_labels"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/_tv_title_labels"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: below this listview i have my button after using this code i am getting more free space left below this listview .

Comment: Code Edited by setting the buttons below the listview.You change the hight of the listview.

Comment: no it is not working still am getting the spaceing issuse below the list now

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/_tv_title_labels"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Profile Labels :"
    android:textColor="#fff000"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />


<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"


--->**android:layout_below="@+id/_tv_title_labels**">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/asda"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/TableLayout01"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/_lv_labels"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" >
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```